# Encrypt/decrypt password in Sqlite (Android)

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, passwords

In developing an Android application that will store certain user date into a sqlite database, how should I handle a user password securely? How can I encrypt the password so that it does not appear "in the clear" in the database, but so I can decrypt it in the application when needed.

Comment: See Peter Gutmann's [Engineering Security](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf). I believe Chapter 7 deals with user passwords. There a lot more to it than simply hashing them or simply salting them, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to store [SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) (or some other type of hash) of the password, and then compare those hashes instead of the actual decrypted passwords.

Storing passwords is a bad practice and is not secure even if they are encrypted. Remember, everything can be broken. The best you could do is to make things more difficult for the hacker.

Comment: MD5 should be considered cryptographically broken and not fit for use. Instead use something like [Bcrypt](http://bcrypt.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Agree that MD5 is a bad example. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Or SHA (like SHA-2 or SHA-3).

Answer (score 0):

Storing user credentials in a database presents many security challenges.  You may want to consider an alternative (e.g. using `OAuth 2.0 Authentication`). We don't need yet another Android app with security vulnerabilities.  Here is a ref for [OAuth 2.0 Authentication](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) from Google.

While one alternative that many folks do use is to "hash" the username and password using an algorithm like `SHA-1` (`MD5` has some vulnerabilities, though it is also used often)