# Storing Encrypted Passwords in SQLite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption, passwords

I am creating an application with a **login** **username** and **password** and I want to **store** the username and **passwords** in SQLite but **I don't want to store the passwords as text**. I want some way to **encrypt** them and then save them in the database.

I have searched and found [Encrypt/decrypt password in Sqlite (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461428/encrypt-decrypt-password-in-sqlite-android) (no solution found)

and  [Android SQlite password encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118793/android-sqlite-password-encryption)  but I  didn't understand how to do it.

Comment: What you want is not encryption but salting and hashing. I'd strongly recommend you read the OWASP materials on this topic, then use an existing library to do the dirty work.

Comment: Is there any other way to do hashing and salting.

Comment: What do you mean? "Any other way," other than what?

Comment: I found PBKDF2 algorithm - PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 . I think this will help me [PBKDF2 Password Hashing Code](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#javasourcecode)